# Solutions for $\frac{3}{x+1}\le\frac{2}{2x+5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Im in search of the solutions for:

$$\frac{3}{x+1}\le\frac{2}{2x+5}$$

So first i tried to combine the two sites:

$$\frac{6x + 15 - 2x + 2}{2x^2 +7x + 5}\le{0}$$

$$\frac{4x + 17}{2x^2 +7x +5}\le{0}$$

My problem is that now i have two solutions for the denominator and i dont know how to continue:

$2x^2+7x+5 = -1 \text{ and } -2.5$

The solution should be: $(-2.5;-1) \cup (-\infty;-3.25)$

Comment: You shouldn't use $\color{red};$ to separate between endpoints on an interval, but rather use $\color{red},$.

Comment: @drhab: $-3.25$ is correct, but $-3.25$ should be included in the solution, not excluded.

Comment: @ user2724695 Insted of 17 there should be 13 .

Comment: It is better to choose for $(x+1)(2x+5)$  as denominator. It saves you the struggling with brackets and brightens the view on the fraction if you are looking for the sign (+ or -) of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you assume assume $2x+5>0$ and $x+1>0$ you end up with :$$3(2x+5)\leq 2(x+1)$$

$$3(2x+5)\leq 2(x+1)\Rightarrow 6x+15\leq2x+2\Rightarrow 4x\leq -13\Rightarrow x\leq??$$

Suppose we assume $x+1$ is positive, then we would end up with above conclusion (Why??)

Suppose we assume $2x+5$ is positive but $x+1 <0$ then???

Please do it by yourself :)

Comment: So in the end i have to make 4 cases right? Thanks

Comment: Yes.... But I can assure you don't have to do all... you have to do at most three... :) I have already said this in the answer.... I would be happy if you say "I have to consider only two" :)

Comment: Accept?? Have you done that completely?

Comment: Yes! Thanks i had the same idea from the beginning but it seemed more easily to short it to one site! And yes i tried all 4 cases! Im not so good in imagine number areas!

Comment: you tried all four cases??? I said not to do so :O I guess you did not understand how simple this could/should be....

Answer (score 7):

Equivalently, you may use this way, if you want. We draw a table as follows. Each row is for a term in the nominator and in factored denominator. I mean $4x+13$;  $x+5/2$ and $x+1$. Then put the roots of these terms on the top of the table as you see from the small one to the large one. Now make some $+$ and $-$ in the boxes to identify the sign of the terms in that subintervals. Finally, find the sign on the main fraction in each column as you see and select the subinterval in which the fraction is negative. This is very similar to @lab’s approach.

[image]

Comment: Same way I use with my students.

Comment: It should be $4x+13$. You took over a mistake of the OP (just like I did)

Comment: @drhab: Ohhh! Thanks.

Comment: You overlooked the $5$-the cell in the first column. Still $4x+17$ there :-).

Answer (score 4):

Write $$\frac{3}{x+1}-\frac{2}{2x+5}=\frac{4x+13}{\left(x+1\right)\left(2x+5\right)}\leq0$$ There are
'special' values $-1,-2.5$ and $-3.25$, found if one of the factors in numerator or denominator is asked to equalize $0$.

Ask yourself the question:
What is the sign of this fraction if I fill in a value $x>-1$ or
$-2.5<x<-1$ or $-3.25<x<-2.5$ or $x\leq-3.25$? The answers to these questions  lead you to the final answer.

Comment: Thanks for warning me. :-)

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac{4x+13}{2x^2+7x+5}=0\implies 4x+13=0$$

$$\frac{4x+13}{2x^2+7x+5}<0 \iff (4x+13)(2x^2+7x+5)<0$$

$$\iff(4x+13)(2x+5)(x+1)<0\iff\left(x+\frac{13}4\right)\left(x+\frac52\right)(x+1)<0$$

So, we need odd number of factor(s) to be $<0$

Comment: It should be $4x+13$. You took over a mistake of the OP (just like I did)

Comment: @drhab, thanks once again :)

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that the difference of the two sides is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{6x+15-2x\color{#C00000}{-}2}{(x+1)(2x+5)}=\frac{4x+\color{#C00000}{13}}{(x+1)(2x+5)}\le0
\end{align}
$$
So there are three points to consider: $-\frac{13}{4}$, $-\frac52$, and $-1$.

To the left of all three points, all three terms, $4x+13$, $x+1$, and $2x+5$, are negative.

Between $-\frac{13}{4}$ and $-\frac52$, only two terms are negative.

Between $-\frac52$ and $-1$, only one term is negative.

To the right of all three points, none of the terms are negative.

Note that all the finite endpoints should be closed, not open, where it doesn't divide by $0$:
$$
\textstyle\left(-\infty,-\frac{13}{4}\right]\cup\left(-\frac52,-1\right)
$$

Comment: I do not get your last sentence.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: the intervals should be closed: e.g. $\left(-\infty,-\frac{13}{4}\right]\cup\left[-\frac52,-1\right]$. However, at $-\frac52$ and $-1$ we would be dividing by $0$.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I allready warned the others (lab and B.S.)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this has been answered but here is a way for **not** making silly mistakes

Starting with
$$\frac{4x+13}{(x+1)(2x+5)} \le 0$$
The correct way to simplify is to multiply by the **square** of the denominator. Since we will be multiplying by a quantity that can never be negative, the sense of inequality will not change. So
$$ (4x+13)(x+1)(2x+5) \le 0$$
Now find the roots and order them in ascending order as $$-3.25, -2.5, -1$$

So to the left of $-3.25$ all the terms in the product is negative.

Between $-3.25$ and $-2.5$ one term is positive, the other two are negative.

Between $-2.5$ and $-1$ two terms are positive, and one negative.

To the right of $-1$ all are positive.

So the final answer: $$(-2.5;-1) \cup (-\infty;-3.25)$$

**Note:** As someone already pointed out there is an error in your original algebra. You had $4x+17$ and it should be $4x+13$

Comment: Shouldn't $-3.25$ be included in the solution?

Comment: You are right! I just copied his answer without thinking!

Comment: Well, there is a way for *not* making silly mistakes :-).

Comment: I am blushing and it is *not* a pretty sight :-)

Comment: I know the feeling...

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=4x+13 \text{and}  g(x)=(x+1)(2x+5)$

and $H(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$
$$H(x)<=0 $$So
either g(x) or H(x) is -ve and another is +ve but

$g(x)>0$  or  $g(x)<0$

since if g(x)=0 than Denominator is zero then  H(x) become Undefined .

Now solve below inequality .

g(x)>0 and h(x)<0

g(x)<0  and h(x)>0

Represent both inequality on **number line**  and take  **intersection** of both parts and

finally take **union** of two solution

This will give you solution .

$(-2.5,-1) \cup (-\infty,-3.25]$

Comment: Why is $-3.25$ excluded?

Comment: @robjohn I corrected now . Thanks for pointing mistake .